Server join and leave logger doesn't save data in file
I had an idea of developing a logging tool for my Discord Bot, so everytime it joins or leaves a server (with the guildCreate and guildDelete function) that it should save some data like the server owner id or even the id of the server etc.
When i tried to code it i came across three problems. Before continuing here is the code for the serverRegsitrationHandler.js file:
const fs = require('fs');

require('../node_modules/dotenv').config();

const registrationFilePath = require('../Data/registeredServers.json');
const joinLogChannelId = process.env.JOIN_CHANNEL_ID;
const leaveLogChannelId = process.env.LEAVE_CHANNEL_ID;

function getRegisteredServers() {
    try {
        const data = fs.readFileSync(registrationFilePath, 'utf8');
        return JSON.parse(data);
    } catch (err) {
        return {};
    }
}

function saveRegisteredServers(data) {
    try {
        const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
        fs.writeFileSync(registrationFilePath, jsonData, 'utf8');
    } catch (err) {
        return {};
    }
}

async function registerServer(guild) {
    const registeredServers = getRegisteredServers();
    const owner = await guild.fetchOwner();

    registeredServers[guild.id] = {
        name: guild.name,
        createdAt: guild.createdAt,
        memberCount: guild.memberCount,
        owner: {
            id: owner.id,
            tag: owner.user.tag,
        },
    };

    saveRegisteredServers(registeredServers);
}

async function logServerJoin(guild) {
    const joinLogChannel = guild.channels.cache.get(joinLogChannelId);
    const owner = await guild.fetchOwner();
    if (joinLogChannel) {
        const embedjoin = {
            color: '000000',
            title: 'Bot joined a server',
            fields: [
                { name: 'Server Name', value: guild.name, inline: false},
                { name: 'Server ID', value: guild.id, inline: false},
                { name: 'Member Count', value: guild.memberCount, inline: false},
                { name: 'Owner', value: `<@${guild.owner}>`, inline: false},
            ],
            timestamp: new Date(),
            footer: { text: 'Left server'}
        }

        await joinLogChannel.send({ embeds: [embedjoin] });
    }
}

async function logServerLeave(guild) {
    const leaveLogChannel = guild.client.channels.cache.get(leaveLogChannelId);
    const owner = await guild.fetchOwner();
    if (leaveLogChannel) {
        const embedleave = {
            color: '000000',
            title: 'Bot left a server',
            fields: [
                { name: 'Server Name', value: guild.name, inline: false},
                { name: 'Server ID', value: guild.id, inline: false},
                { name: 'Member Count', value: guild.memberCount, inline: false},
                { name: 'Owner', value: `<@${guild.owner}>`, inline: false},
            ],
            timestamp: new Date(),
            footer: { text: 'Left server'}
        }

        await leaveLogChannel.send({ embeds: [embedleave] });
    }

    const registeredServers = getRegisteredServers();
    delete registeredServers[guild.id];
    saveRegisteredServers(registeredServers);
}

module.exports = { registerServer, logServerJoin, logServerLeave };

Here the serverRegistration.js file (which is located in a events folder):
const client = require('../main.js')

client.on('guildCreate', async (guild) => {
    registerServer(guild);
    logServerJoin(guild);
});

client.on('guildDelete', async (guild) => {
    logServerLeave(guild);
});

Now onto the problems:

It doesn't save the Data in the storage (registeredServers.json) file.

It doesn't send the Embed when it joins a server.

It does not mention the username nor id from the server owner.


I tried troubleshooting and eventually after some time i made it more worse than it was before. I hope anyone could help me with this problem. I would appreciate any help.
Kind Regards

Are the guildCreate and guildDelete events actually emitting? You may need to set proper gateway intents.
